# Visual Studio 2012 BI error connecting to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2014

I am currently following a tutorial of SQL Server 2014 Business Intelligence, and now I'm stuck with VS 2012 data tools in the following:

1. I'm using the AdventureWorks2012DW database as a datasource (fine till now)
2. When I create the datasourceview and the cube it works fine;
3. But when I want to deploy it ask for server password (which I enter correctly) and when processing the cube it fails with the following message:

   > no connection could be made because the destination host actively refuse it
   > 127.0.0.1:2883 (system)

My question is how came the machine refuse the connection if I was able to load the AdventureWorks2012DW and use the datasourceview? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After many days of work i finally figure it out:

The problem was the fact that SQL Server Ananlisys Service and SQL Server Browser both reserve ports 2383 and 2382 and my AS was listening in another port (5883) the fix is or to alow bhot port in windows firewall or to connect with : in Visual Studio to process the cube!